# Facebook Graph API post comment fails

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FB graph API to post comments on different posts, but it does not work every time. There are posts that are okay to be "commented" and others fail every time. I'm using a Facebook user auth token (not a group or app token) to post comments.

The error returned is `(#200) Permissions error`.

At first I thought the post is not public and my user don't have a permission to comment on it, but when I go to it via web browser and logged in as the same user - he can manualy post comments on it. So via web it is working and via API it produces permissions error #200.

And just to mention again - I'm able to comment on certain posts with no issues.

Here is sample of my code that I think it is a fairly standard:

```
$oFacebook = new Facebook($config);
try {
    $oFacebook->api('/'.$iEventId.'/comments', 'POST', array(
        'message' => $sComment,
        'access_token' => $sAccessToken
    ));
} catch (Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

$sComment is small plain text.
$sAccessToken is saved in DB access token. When I test it in the FB debug tools it says the token has `publish_stream` scope which is needed to post comments.

The same situation can be reproduced via [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), so I assume it is not code-related issue.

In terms of reproducibility, here is one post ID that CAN'T be commented via API: 381578255242674. You can generate random access token in the explorer and try to POST to /381578255242674/comments.

And here is one post ID that CAN be commented: 265070490272041.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tying to request details about the first post you mentioned – http://graph.facebook.com/381578255242674 – just throws an exception, _“Unsupported get request”_ (whereas the second one actually delivers some data). Are you sure about the first one being a valid post on Facebook?

Comment: Yeah, you can view it on www.facebook.com/381578255242674

Comment: After some investigation it seems all troubling posts are posts that someone made at another person/group wall. Posts that someone made at his own wall are OK. Is this expected behavior?